# How to fix Substring not found Error in python when string is being searched by another string?

Tags: python, list, authentication

I have a login program for a project, but when I try to find the password that matches the user, it gives me a "substring not found" error. Here's my code (yes I will hash the passwords after I get t to work):

```
Usernames = [
"John",
"Mark"    
]
Passwords = [
"abc",
"xyz"
]
username = input("Username: ")
password = input("Password: ")
if username in Usernames and password in Passwords:
    user = Usernames.index(username)
    if password.index(user): #error happens here
        print("Logged In!")
    else:
        print("Username or password incorecct.")
else:
    print("User not found.")
```

Comment: `password in Passwords` -- Phew, don't do that. That'll compare one user's password against *any other users' passwords*.

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mre] including example input, expected output, and actual output, i.e. the full error message with traceback.

Comment: I suggest keeping a dictionary mapping username to their password, instead of having two separate lists of usernames and passwords. Hash lookup will also be faster than list.index, in case you want to check if it’s a valid user.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use parallel lists, use a dict instead.

```
users = {
    "John": "abc",
    "Mark": "xyz",
    }
username = input("Username: ")
password = input("Password: ")
if username in users and password == users[username]:
    print("Logged In!")
else:
    print("Username or password incorrect.")
```

I removed the `User not found` message because you already have one for `Username or password incorrect`, which is probably better practice (though I'm not much of a security guy).